# While uploading Excel Showing Undefined array key "Sheet 1" in Laravel (Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for uploading Excel, But While uploading Excel to the system it's showing Error like this

Undefined array key "Sheet 1"

The package is used upload excel is laravel Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

```
Excel::import(new NewProducts($import->id), $path)->chain([
    new AfterImport($import->id)
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution it was a problem with packages, I have updated the package phpoffice/phpspreadsheet. Now working fine